# Issue downloading file with safari browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, sharepoint-2010

I am developing an web application where some **.docx**, **.xlsx** need to be download from the web app, the application work as expected in all top browsers except for safari, when i try to download a file with **safari** I get as a download the .aspx page instead of the .docx file, ¿How can I fix this issue?, this is the implemented code for file download, Thanks in advance for the help.

```
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PruebaSharePoint.docx");
    Response.TransmitFile("~/PruebaSharePoint.docx");
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
```

Comment: How this is related to SharePoint? When you get "download the .aspx page" is it file name wrong or content is wrong too?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Sometimes i get the binary content of the file print on the page or downloaded the .aspx page that host the application not the .docx file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was solved by replacing this:

```
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
```

with this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type","application/ms-excel");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this for the content type:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word.document.12";
```

and add this to the last line:

```
Response.End();
```

Comment: I would note what ::End() does.